# Hide Grub Menu - Linux Mint 19.2

Tags: linux, linux-mint, grub

For some reason on my Samsung Ativ Book4, after installing Linux Mint, the grub menu is showing and I want to be be able to boot directly into Linux Mint 19.2 without having a loader showing the different option.

Grub Version: 2.02

grub settings (/etc/default/grub):

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

grub.cfg

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  # GRUB lacks write support for lvm, so recordfail support is disabled.
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod lvm
insmod ext2
set root='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'  aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
if [ $grub_platform = efi ]; then
  set timeout=30
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod lvm
    insmod ext2
    set root='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'  aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-25-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root ro  quiet splash acpi_backlight=native $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-25-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892' {
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce, with Linux 5.0.0-25-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-25-generic-advanced-aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'  aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.0.0-25-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-25-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root ro  quiet splash acpi_backlight=native $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-25-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce, with Linux 5.0.0-25-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.0.0-25-generic-recovery-aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'  aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.0.0-25-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-25-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-25-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce, with Linux 4.15.0-58-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-58-generic-advanced-aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'  aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-58-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-58-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root ro  quiet splash acpi_backlight=native $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-58-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce, with Linux 4.15.0-58-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-58-generic-recovery-aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'  aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-58-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-58-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-58-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce, with Linux 4.15.0-54-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-54-generic-advanced-aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'  aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-54-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-54-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root ro  quiet splash acpi_backlight=native $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-54-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce, with Linux 4.15.0-54-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-54-generic-recovery-aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/7OXWq6-hDYa-mIOt-kcC0-LxAB-YkTO-F0UIUV/S5oEN5-cTwE-a0gl-doLd-fAo7-wysV-cc24v5'  aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root aa2d0601-b160-4937-962c-3064a5462892
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-54-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-54-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-54-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Settings are same for both virtual box and samsung laptop.

Using VirtualBox, the grub menu is hidden, can anyone help me hide the menu for the laptop?

Comment: What file are your grub settings from?

Comment: @Peschke I updated my post with the location, but `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: Have you reinstalled GRUB so that the new settings are installed into `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`?

Comment: @Ned64 No I haven't, I only just installed Linux Mint 19.2, and haven't changed any settings for both VirtualBox and on my laptop. I can try that later, but is there a reason why it works for VirtualBox but not on the laptop even when they are using the same grub versions and same settings?

Comment: @dree The settings file you have edited, `/etc/default/grub` is read not during boot but during a re-install of GRUB.  This happens when you update the kernel, among other things. Ultimately the settings work iff they are in `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.  Check that file on both systems (also, last change time of that file) then perhaps we see whether it was the missing update.  After checking, try `update-grub` (call as root to update that file) and let us know.

Comment: @Ned64 Alright, both VirtualBox and laptop do not have the file at location `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` or have a folder `grub2` so i'll still need to install grub2 for both correct? Is there a good tutorial on how to do it? I switched from Windows so I am new and don't want to mess up the computers

Comment: Did you install Mint with LVM?

Comment: @dree No, don't install GRUB - you do have a bootloader, otherwise Linux wouldn't boot at all.  You wrote that you have version 2.02. In fact, you need to configure your existing bootloader!  Perhaps the files are at a different location?  Try `find /boot | fgrep .cfg` to see whether you can find that config file!  PS: Perhaps one of the systems has EFI? Then the location is different but the `find` command should find it!

Comment: run `update-grub` (as root) after editing `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: @Ned64 Oh sorry, yes I have the grub.cfg in `/boot/grub/`. Is there something specifically I should be looking for in the grub.cfg or just when it was last modified? I  have messed with the grub file trying to get my brightness controls to work, but I reverted back to original settings afterwards and did run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @ajgringo619 No, I didn't.

Comment: @dree for the moment let's look at the last modified date: please check that `update-grub` has really changed that config file (perhaps run it again), then boot to see whether the problem persists. If it does, please post the config file from the system where it does not work by editing your Question!

Comment: @Ned64 It does indeed change, but problem still persists. I've updated post with grub.cfg file

Comment: @dree Thanks. Are both GRUB versions identical?

Comment: @Ned64 Yes, they are I found that there is a bug because my computer uses EFI, I assume it will be fixed in next update. I found that commenting out some lines of code in 00_header doesn't show the grub menu